# Cannot start MySQL anymore in DirectAdmin

Tags: mysql, directadmin

I stopped the DirectAdmin MySQL service in the Serice Admin panel and wanted to start it again but it doesn't start anymore. When I try it on the command line I get this error:

[image]

Any ideas? Server = Debian 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved after I updated MariaDB from 10.0 to 10.2.